# Node.js - How to grab the class names from a .scss file

Tags: node.js, sass, fs

I wanted to ask if anyone knows of a good solution for how to use node.js to look in a .scss file and grab all the classes listed and to then put them in either an object or an array?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with this is that you are going to need the sass folder to be available to you server, this is not a recommended practice since you only publish the css compiled file, there is no need to also publish the dev assets. 
However if you do so, you will need to read .scss file using node and from there use a regex to match the .class strings inside the file.

This will make the reading of the file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readSassFile () {
    fs.readFile('./public/scss/components/_styles.scss', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        regexArray(data);
    });
}
```

As you can see, at the end if the readFile retrieves the file with success, I'm calling a function regexArray() and sending the data of the file loaded.

In the regexArray function you need to define a regex to evaluate the string of the file loaded.

```
function regexArray (data) {

    var re = /\.\S*/g;
    var m;
    var classArray = [];

    while ((m = re.exec(data)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        classArray.push(m[0]);
    }

    console.log(classArray);
}
```

the var re is the regular expression matching any string starting with a . and ending with a non-whitespace character which will match your css class names.

then we evaluate the m variable when is different from null and store the results in the array classArray, then you can log it to see the results.

I made the test with the path that is in the fs.readFile method, you can change it for you own path.